# Upgrading Apache http server 2.0 directly to 2.4

Tags: apache, http, webserver

I have gone through several suggestions online for upgrading Apache HTTP server 2.0 to 2.2 and then 2.2 to 2.4. But I want to somehow upgrade Apache HTTP server from 2.0 directly to 2.4. How it can be done?

Comment: You'd probably have more luck with this question on http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Cristik why do you advise to ask this on superuser? ServerFault is the proper place to ask this question. IMO